# Different definitions of existence of expected value

Tags: probability, statistics

In Casella & Berger (2nd Edition), the expected value is defined to exist only if E|X|<∞.

In PTE by Durrett, the expected value is defined to exist if $E(X^+)<∞$ or $E(X^−)<∞$, where $X^+ = max(0, X)$ and $X^- = - min(0, X)$.

I believe both textbooks are widely used. In fact, my distribution theory course and mathematical statistics course use these two definitions respectively.

My question is, which definition is used more nowadays?

Comment: Your notation is kind of hard to understand as is. You’ll have a better chance at finding a good answer here if you type it up using Latex and explain your notation.

Comment: Ash makes the distinction between "the expectation of $X$ exists" and "the expectaction of $X$ is finite" the former means $E(X^+) < \infty$ or $E(X^-) < \infty$ and $E(X) = E(X^+) - E(X^-)$ which makes sense since it does not take the form $\infty - \infty.$ The relation "the expectation of $X$ is finite" means $E(X^+) < \infty$ and $E(X^-) < \infty.$ (Ash's "Real Analisys and Probability")

Comment: I'm pretty sure $X^- =\max(0,-X) = -\min(X,0).$ This implies $X=X^+-X^-.$

Comment: Thanks, William! Fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we say the expectation of $X$ exists iff $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$, i.e. in the first sense because this is directly inherited from measure theory, where a function $f$ is said to be $L^1$ iff $\int|f|<\infty$.

However Durrett chose the second way simply because for many results(actually, nearly all I think) in his book the infinite mean is acceptable, as long as at least one side of the integral(the positive or the negative) is bounded. This shows a greater generality of those theorems, so hard to say whether this choice of definitoin is good or not. Your call.